# Allow duplicate columns pandas / refresh column dtypes upon updating column header

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I'm creating a dataframe out of a string data, the header of which have duplicate columns. Because of pandas default check to auto-rename in case of duplicate columns, it adds '.1, .2, and so on' suffix to each duplicate.

```py
formatted_data = "a|b|c|a\n1|xyz|3|4"

final_data = StringIO(formatted_data)

df = pd.read_csv(final_data, sep='|')
```

**Output df:**

```
a    b    c    a.1
1    xyz  3    4
```

I followed the solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19383)

```py
df = pd.read_csv(final_data, sep='|', header=None)

df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0], copy=False).iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output df is as expected but it messes up with the metadata forcing the dtype for all columns to be **dtype('O')**. This dtype has cascading effects to my transformation code where I create an arrow_table out of the transformed_df.

```py
arrow_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False)
```

It errors out: **pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: ('an integer is required (got type str)', 'Conversion failed for column a with type object')**

To fix the above error, before creating the table, I assign the df type to str & the issue gets resolved:

```py
df = df.astype(str)
```

But the table's metadata stores **'pandas_type': "unicode"** for all the cols.

The end-state of my datafile is parquet & as parquet operations are highly-dependent on metadata, the above data_type is not the expected.

Is there a pandas in-built option or work around to get the expected df without losing the dtype or auto re-assigning the dtype based on values:

**Expected df:**

```
a    b    c    a
1    xyz  3    4
```

```py
df.a.dtype

> dtype('int64')
```

Comment: You *really* should avoid duplicate column names. This creates a whole host of issues because you now need to worry about whether `df['a']` returns a `DataFrame` or a `Series`. As an example, even in your simple expected output `df.a.dtype` will return an `AttributeError` because for DataFrames you need `.dtypes`, note the s on the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only replacing the columns with their non-dot/numbered versions, you can use regex and a list comprehension

```
import re

df

    a   b   c   a.1 test.1abc
0   1   xyz 3   4   5

df.dtypes

a       int64
b      object
c       int64
a.1     int64
dtype: object

df.columns=[re.sub(r'(\.\d\b)','',i) for i in df.columns]    

df

    a   b   c   a   test.1abc
0   1   xyz 3   4   5

df.dtypes

a       int64
b      object
c       int64
a.1     int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: But what if a column-name is : **test.1_abc**?
..this is not added by pandas!

Comment: Edited the regex to check for end-of-word boundary. This is one possible solution, there may be better ones if the input data looks different than what you've provided

Comment: This is a good solution but it is not generic enough I think. There can be a scenario where the column_name is **test_2.12**. The above solution would parse this where it shouldn't be. My bad, I should've included all the possibilities in the question

Comment: I created a work around that I believe should work in any scenario. Will post it in new comment!

Comment: Thanks for this solution though :)

Answer (score 0):

when creating the string in the 1st place, I added _counter to the header row which made each column header unique & then after reading it into the df, parsed & removed the _counter from the column name. Below is the code:

```py
formatted_data = "a_1|b_2|c_3|a_4\n1|xyz|3|4"

df = pd.read_csv(final_data, sep='|')
```

**Output:**

```
a_1   b_2   c_3   a_4
1     xyz   3     4
```

Removing the added *_counter*:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_', 1).str[0]
```

**Output:**

```
a   b   c   a
1   xyz 3   4
```

How I created the *formatted_df*?
**Ans:** it may vary from use case-to-use case. For me, I was reading directly from a file & so while reading the first line I added the _counter before the pipe(s)